# rspec + remarkable + before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, before-filter

How do I test before_filter with rspec and [remarkable](http://remarkable.rubyforge.org/rails/). With only rspec I would do something like:

```
 controller.stub(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
```

But with remarkable this results in:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<Class:0x7f8f056ef3c0> (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expects :logged_in?, :on => proc { @controller }, :returns => true
```

(solution found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/remarkable-core/browse_thread/thread/8bb488bd63e941f2))